# Why would a bash function be enclosed within a variable using quotes?

Tags: bash

I've seen how several Bash functions are often constructed, but I've never quite seen something like this:

```
TEST=" 
function mined {
    // do something here
}
mined
"
```

I'm a little confused as to why anyone would create a function like above as opposed to simply normally creating the function and calling it? So if I understand this correctly, does the TEST variable represent a call to the mined function?

Comment: As you've written it, that's not a function at all; it's a string that happens to *look* like a shell function definition, but it doesn't actually define a function. You could later do something like `eval "$TEST"`, which would execute it as shell syntax and hence define a function, but without that it's just a string. (BTW, `eval` is almost always a bad idea, and I can't think of a sane reason to use it this way.)

Comment: Maybe the variable's value acts as a block comment. The string contains not only a function definition, but also "executes" that function in the last line.